# Why is my Rails app on Heroku soemtimes displaying apostrophes as HTML entities?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, html-entities

Sometimes we have jobs whose name has an apostrophe in it.  I always want those apostrophes to display as `'` , never as their HTML entity  (`&#x27;`).

The apostrophe displays correctly on most pages most of the time.  But in some instances, the apostrophe displays as the HTML entity instead.  Here's a [screen-capture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-3b7oCW72eGUUFXNFRKdkpWUGc/edit?usp=sharing) showing the behavior:

The apostrophes in the "Notes" field (a textarea) display correctly, but not in the "Job name" and "Display as" fields. Luckily, the apostrophes display correctly on the public-facing side, and I only see this behavior on the admin-side.

This sentence is going to sound insane, but stick with me, here:  When I look at a page's source code where this problem occurs, it looks like the leading ampersand in the apostrophe's html entity is being replaced with the HTML entity for ampersand, thus becoming `&amp;#x27;`

Here's [a gist of the form's code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4b541401cf220b3c1430).

When I look up this job's record in console, the job name and display name are "Job's Got An Apostrophe", so I know (think?) I'm not storing the HTML entity in my database.  My database.yml specifies unicode encoding.  It's a PostgreSQL 9.2.7 database.  Not sure what other information is needed to help resolve this, if any.

Comment: please share the code of that form please

Comment: Updated the question with a link to the form's code.

Comment: please look on database for that record, what do u see? it seem to me that there was not html_safe. look up on html_safe on rails documentation

Comment: Edited the question again.  Wasn't originally clear enough that I used console to look at the record for that job in my database.  My understanding of html_safe is that it allows html to be entered in a form without being escaped.  Is an apostrophe considered HTML?

Comment: Had I mentioned that this is an older app running on Rails 2.3.16, perhaps [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9108) may have helped explain the problem and/or solution:

Comment: you are using Rails 2.3.16 ??

Comment: In my defense, I'm a one-man 'team' who had no previous Ruby experience before this app. I am working on a complete rewrite in the latest Ruby while we nurse the current app along until I'm done. I added the monkeypatch mentioned by "shireeshj" [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9108).  I'll crawl back under my rock now and come out when I'm running production on Rails4.  ;)